# how to auto deploy vue js to cpanel using github action only file inside dist folder

Tags: vue.js, deployment

I have a vue js project let say the name is my_web , I have successfully deployed it to folder public_html in cpanel , but the problem is that the uploaded files are all files in my_web . I want only files in the dist folder to be uploaded

here is the code workflow

```
  on: 
    push:
     branches:
      - main
     name:  Deploy website on push
     jobs:
        web-deploy:
          name:  Deploy
          runs-on: ubuntu-latest
     steps:
    - name:  Get latest code
          uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Use Node.js 14
         uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
         node-version: '14'
  
    - name:  Build Project
      run: |
        npm install
        npm run build    
    - name:  Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.0
      with:
       server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
       username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
       password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert at the end of your code:

```
with:
       server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
       username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
       password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
       local-dir: dist/
```

Comment: thank you this is actually work "./dist/"